# Remember me Login page with JSP Servlet using database at backend?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, authentication, remember-me

This is my login JSP. And its working - means: values are going to servlet.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Login || Dreamer</title>
    </head>
    <style>
        h1{
            color:chocolate;
        }
        label{
            color:royalblue;
            font-family:Arial;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        #ms{
            color:green;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        #ms2{
            color:red;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <center>
            <h1>Login Page</h1>
        </center>
        <br>
        <br>
        <center>
            ${error}
            <div id="ms">
            </div>
            <br>
            <form action="Controller" method="post">
                <tr>   <label >
                    Username:
                    <label><input type="text" placeholder="Example@domain.com"  name="username" />
                </tr><br><br>
                <tr>
                    <label >
                    password:
                    <label><input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
                </tr>
                <br><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" />Remember me<label>
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
            </form>
            <a href="register.jsp">Create new User</a>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

**This is my servlet .**

```
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
    String uname="root";
    String pass="root";
    String url="jdbc:mysql:///e_learning";
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String action=request.getParameter("action");
        HttpSession session=request.getSession();
        if(action==null){
            Account account=checkCookie(request);
            if(action==null)
                if(account==null)
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request, response);
                else{
                    ConnectionTest ct=new ConnectionTest();
                    Connection conn=ct.getConn();
                    try{
                        psmt=conn.prepareStatement(qry);
                        psmt.setString(1,account.getUsername());
                        psmt.setString(2,account.getPassword());
                        rs=psmt.executeQuery();
                        if(rs.next()){
                            out.print("yes outer");
                            session.setAttribute("username", account.getUsername());
                            request.getRequestDispatcher("main.jsp").forward(request, response);
                        }else{
                            request.setAttribute("error", "Account's Invalid");
                            request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request, response);

                        }
                    }catch(Exception e){

                    }
                }   

        }else{
            if(action.equals("logout")){
                session.removeAttribute("username");
                Cookie[] cookies=request.getCookies();
                for(Cookie ck: cookies){
                    if(ck.getName().equals("username")){
                        ck.setMaxAge(0);
                        response.addCookie(ck);
                    }
                    if(ck.getName().equals("password")){
                        ck.setMaxAge(0);
                        response.addCookie(ck);
                    }
                }
                request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request, response);            
            }
        }
    }
    private Account checkCookie(HttpServletRequest request){

        Cookie[] cookies=request.getCookies();
        Account account=null;
        if(cookies==null)
            return null;
        else{
            String username="",password="";
            for(Cookie ck: cookies){
                if(ck.getName().equals("usernamec"));
                username=ck.getValue();
                if(ck.getName().equals("passwordp"));
                password=ck.getValue();
            }
            if(!username.isEmpty()&& !password.isEmpty())
                account=new Account(username,password);
        }
        return account;
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String action=request.getParameter("action");

        HttpSession session=request.getSession();
        if(action==null){
            String username=request.getParameter("username");
            String password=request.getParameter("password");

            boolean remember=request.getParameter("remember")!=null;
            **This is the Connection class i have write the connection string here and I am making the object of this class then accessing the method of connection here**
            ConnectionTest cn=new ConnectionTest(); 
            Connection con=cn.getConn();
            try{
                psmt=con.prepareStatement(qry);
                psmt.setString(1, username);
                psmt.setString(2, password);
                rs=psmt.executeQuery();
                if(rs.next()){
                    out.print("yessssss");
                    session.setAttribute("username",username);
                    if(remember){
                        Cookie cku=new Cookie("usernamec", username);
                        cku.setMaxAge(3600);
                        response.addCookie(cku);
                        Cookie ckp=new Cookie("passwordp", password);
                        cku.setMaxAge(3600);
                        response.addCookie(ckp);
                    }
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("main.jsp").forward(request, response);
                }else{
                    request.setAttribute("error", "Acchhhhhhount's Invalid");
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request, response);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
            }
        }else{
        }
    }
```

This is sending the cookies to browser. But its not remembering the login even though I have checked the "Remember me" check box. Can any one tell me where I am wrong in this code.

Comment: It is not a good idea to catch exceptions silently when searching for an error. As a first step I would insert a `e.printStackTrace()` in every catch block and see if there's some output in the servlet container's log file.

Comment: BTW: You know that your HTML is pretty invalid? If not, paste it at [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) and take a look at the output.

Comment: it is not the issue of html. JSP page working well i can get values from there to servlet.